# AVPlayer volume is not adjusting while AirPlay

Tags: volume, avplayer, airplay

I am working on a custom audio player.
I am using a UISlider to adjust volume.It is working fine when I play on iPad.
But when I use AirPlay volume does not adjust.

Here is my code to adjust volume.

```
UISlider* slide = sender;

   NSArray *audioTracks = [myPlayer.currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
        [audioInputParams setVolume:slide.value atTime:myPlayer.currentTime];
        [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
    }
    AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
    [myPlayer.currentItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix];
```